# What is the big O of my algorithm?

Tags: big-o

I need help with finding the big oh of this algorithm. This is a search algorithm that is dividing and conquering my array of size n to find the first occurrence of false, a is an array.

```
n=a.length;
i=0;
while(a[i]){
   i += n/2;
   n=n/2;
}
       i -= n;
while(a[i])
   i++;
```

//hopefully, i will stop at the first occurrence of false.

Comment: The description seems to indicate a binary search, which is `O(log n)`. Your code doesn't look like that, however

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to, I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first part:

```
n=a.length;
i=0;
while(a[i]){
   i += n/2;
   n=n/2;
}
```

executes in O(lg N): i = (n-n), (n-n/2), (n-n/4), ...

But it might have a problem. Let us suppose that N=63. Then:

```
i = 0   and n = 63, so n/2 is 31.5, and being an integer, it is 31.
i = 31  and n = 31, so n/2 is ... 15
i = 46  and n = 15, so n/2 is ... 7
i = 53  and n = 7, so n/2 ... 3
i = 56  and n = 3, so n/2 ... 1
i = 57  and n = 1, so n/2 = 0
```

And now if `a[57]` is `true` the cycle will never end, because adding n=0 to the final index will leave it unchanged.

If you exit the cycle with some nonzero `n`, you are at `n/k` for some k, and start incrementing i.

```
i -= n;
while(a[i])
   i++;
```

Here you add `n/k` complexity, which is O(N) in the worst case and O(1) in the best, but in both cases you will access illegal memory as soon as `i` overshoots the array boundary, and probably coredump. You should do something like

```
i -= n;
while((i < n) && (a[i]))
   i++;
```

Otherwise, your algorithm might be anywhere between O(lg N) and O(N), but chances are that it will either never terminate, or terminate abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching through an array which contains just boolean true/false values, then these values could not be sorted in any way which would allow for the binary search which you are describing.  If the array contained a sorted list of values then you would be able to use the divide and conquering of binary search with O(log n).  To find the first occurrence of a false you would need to check each value of the array with worst case being O(n).

```
int i = 0;
for (i; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == false){
        break;
    }

}
return i;
```